# WinSCP: Not all files are listed

Tags: file, winscp

I'm using WinSCP to connect to my Server via sftp. I have an images folder with 33935 files. I used `ls -1U | wc -l` via ssh to figure that out. But WinSCP is only showing me 9998 files. (Below the list is "... 9.998") And if I copy the whole folder to my PC, there are also only 9998 files. I have not found something about a file limit from WinSCP. And there are no hidden files. I have activated the setting to show hidden files. What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this answer [here](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25313):

> The server deliberately limits directory listings to 10000 objects. Since the special . and .. directories are sent, too, you are left with 9998 usable objects. 
>   Either the admin is aware of it as planned limitation (to cut bandwidth), or the admin is lazy (the limit is set by default in some server software). 
>   Contacting server support is the correct way.